# How to Convert Integer to Varchar(8) using spark scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to convert int datafield to nvarchar with leading zeros

example:

```
a.  400 -> 00004.00
b.  6300 -> 00063.00
c.  6100 -> 00061.00
```

Comment: Numeric (integer) values have to be formatted like this: xxxxx.00 (left padding zeros with lengh 5 + decimal point + 2 decimal), data type will be varchar(8).Here some examples from the below sample load:
a. 400  00004.00
b. 6300  00063.00
c. 6100  00061.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lpad` to add zeros:

```
val df = Seq((400),(6300),(6100)).toDF("column")

val df2 = df.withColumn("varchar8", concat_ws(".", substring(lpad($"column", 7, "0"), 1, 5), lit("00")))

df2.show
+------+--------+
|column|varchar8|
+------+--------+
|   400|00004.00|
|  6300|00063.00|
|  6100|00061.00|
+------+--------+
```

Comment: varchar(8) is datatype in spark scala

Comment: `these datatypes should only used for parsing, and should NOT be used anywhere else. Any instance of these data types should be replaced by a StringType before analysis` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/VarcharType.html

Comment: @user13748181 varchar cannot be used in dataframes. you need to use strings to represent them, as I did in my code.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am looking exactly this solution.

Comment: can you please explain how you did that

Comment: Use lpad to add zeros, and then append `.00`

Comment: how can we convert 47 to 00047.00

Comment: `concat_ws(".", lpad($"column", 5, "0"), lit("00"))`